# how to update current timestamp when user updates record each time in php pdo

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

This is the table -

[image: Table pic]

In the above demo file I have stored the image name and path and an automatic timestamp when image is uploaded.

Now when I update the image , I can't get the 'date_of_entry' column to update each time I update the old image.

And the 'date_of_entry' does not get inputed manually by user in form .

So how can i make the  'date_of_entry' field to UPDATE timestamp each time when image gets updated?

Comment: See the manual under https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/timestamp-initialization.html

Comment: Can you share your PHP code as well?

Comment: Maybe this help `UPDATE table_name SET date_of_entry = NOW() WHERE id = :id` But you could better have 2 columns one for date entry and one for date changed. While making the column you could add automaticaly add a timestamp when the row gets updated

Comment: @Baracuda078 i already tried using NOW() but it throiws "undefined function NOW()" .

Comment: Then how does your query looks like? Mysql dont throw errors like that

Comment: it worked with $t = date('d-m-Y H:i:s'); with datatype varchar only.However When i used datatype datetime or timestamp it shows 00-00-000 00:00:00 after update. SO i used datatype varchar (i know which is not the right way). But, now i cant figure out why date() doesnot show correct value in datetime datatype but varchar.    PS: i created all the above in a new column  named last_edited_on.

Comment: That's because MySQL datetime format is `Y-m-d H:i:s`, not `d-m-Y H:i:s`